# What does it mean for an empire to fight for relevance?

Tags: war, political-history, ottoman-empire

I read about the [Armenian genocide](https://encyclopedia.ushmm.org/content/en/article/the-armenian-genocide-1915-16-overview) that it was a last-ditch effort from the Ottomans to fight for relevance. Is "fighting for relevance" a common expression in historic commentary? What does it mean for an empire to become irrelevant? Is there some special way to prevent this? Is becoming irrelevant different from losing territory?

Comment: It would help a lot if you can get us an actual quote. The vast majority of questions about things other people said about history end up being explained by looking at the exact thing that was said, and context around it. And of course we don't like anonymous "this drunk in a bar told me ..." questions, because the world's full of insane randos. It would be folly to try to address them all.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: I think you mean **Armenian**!

Comment: Both world wars were, basically, fights for relevance, of Germany (and in WW1, Austria-Hungary) in Europe, and Japan in the Pacific. At the same time, Britain lost its empire in these wars, even though the lands were not taken forcefully from them -- they just lost the power to keep it all under their control. In a way, you could say that Russia is currently fighting for relevance as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without a quote, I can only answer based on an assumption: that the quote was stating an Empire becomes irrelevant because internal forces are fighting against its being. If you consider this meaning, then several examples could be given:

- Colonial empires in the 20th century when people being part of colonized areas as well as the metropolitan nation (France, United Kingdom...) wanted to go out of the colony
- Roman Empire when parts of the Empire made secession: interesting examples because this Empire managed to recover parts of itself (Palmyra city notably)
- Countries of the Russian Empire who became independent

Answer (score -1):

When an empire is in decline it can lose control of its economy, its social structures and its subjects.  It can face, both internal and external, military and political threats.  To its subjects and its neighbours, the imperial government becomes increasingly irrelevant.  People stop paying taxes, imperial laws and decrees are ignored.  It can become an empire in name only, at which point the government may try to reassert its authority; to show that it still matters, to **fight for relevance**.

In the case of the Ottoman Empire, in 1915, it was in a state of significant decline.  It had suffered military defeats and lost territory in the First World War (on the side of the German/Austro-Hungarians) and the war had lead to diplomatic isolation.  The economy was in trouble, there was internal religious, social and political unrest.  The piece you read is claiming that the Armenian Genocide was an attempt by the Ottoman Empire to show that it still mattered.